# What does the savethread / restore thread do?

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, numba

This is a follow up from this question:

[When does a numba function compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27510838/when-does-a-numba-function-compile)

I am confused as to what this part of the code does:

```
from ctypes import pythonapi, c_void_p
savethread = pythonapi.PyEval_SaveThread
savethread.argtypes = []
savethread.restype  = c_void_p

restorethread = pythonapi.PyEval_RestoreThread
restorethread.argtypes = [c_void_p]
restorethread.restype  = None
```

What is the savethread / restorethreads and the argtypes / restypes?

I read a bit here:

https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock

but got lost to be honest...

**Motivation**
The motivation for the question is that I tried to implement something similar to this example:

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.15.1/examples.html#multi-threading

but instead of passing a "result" list or pointers I use a numpy array.

```
result = np.zeros([N1, N2, Nthreads], dtype=np.float)
```

then call the function with:

```
(result[:,:,iThread],) + args
```

as argument but there seems to be some crashing of writing to the location. Ie the result some of `iThread` ends up in a different location (let's call it `iThread2`) thus overwriting results.

If you want more info on this let me know. I tried to add only some basics to avoid cluttering the question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is used for calling a C function, in this case the functions are `PyEval_SaveThread` and `PyEval_RestoreThread`.

`savethread = pythonapi.PyEval_SaveThread` keeps a reference to the function `pythonapi.PyEval_SaveThread` in the variable `savethread`, so that way when you call the function later using `savethread()` it's as if you called `pythonapi.PyEval_SaveThread()`.

`restype` and `argtypes` define the expected C types for the return and argument values respectively. The `restype` attribute must always be set to a single C type (or `None`) and the `argtypes` attribute must always be set to a list (or tuple) of C types. These should be set as C functions accept and return strict types (whereas Python functions are not strictly typed). E.g. `savethread.restype  = c_void_p` says that the expected return type when you call `savethread()` will be of the C type `void *`.

For more information read up on [the ctypes docs.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html)

Not a complete answer but hope that helps.

**Edit:** argtypes and restype define the argument and return types of the function they are attributed with. Argtypes is always a list and return type is a single item.

E.g. for savethread there are no arguments, so the list of argument types is empty. The return type is c_void_p which means the return value you get from calling that function will be interpreted as a pointer. it's important in this case as the pointer will just be an integer, but the pointer type means that this is integer is a memory address (probably to a thread I guess).

Comment: thanks for the answer. with regards to `restype`, `argtypes` the return and argument types of what? That is what I don't get. Since when `savethread` is called it doesn't have a function as an argument for example..

Comment: They are they are the types of the function argument and return values, see my edit.